# Export Google Document as HTML

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to grab the HTML version of a Google Document to hopefully use in a templating scenario:

```
function getAsHtml(fileId){
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  var htmlLink = file.exportLinks[MimeType.HTML];
  var token = ScriptApp.getOauthToken();
  var options = {
    headers : {
      Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  }
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(htmlLink, options);
  return resp.getContentText();
}
```

The problem is that this returns the Google login page. When I visit the `htmlLink` in a browser, it downloads fine because I'm logged in. So this makes me think that this authorization method won't work here. How would an application use the Drive Api to export a Google Document if not using the OAuth token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code worked for me. You may have to replace

```
  var token = ScriptApp.getOauthToken();
```

with

```
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
```